# In baby rudin, absolutely converge, uniformly converge, and so on...

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question in baby rudin p.165, exercise #4.
The problem is :

Consider 
f(x)=$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2x}$

For what values of x  does the series converge absolutely? On what intervals does it converge uniformly? On what intervals does it fail to converge uniformly? Is f  continuous wherever the series converges? Is f  bounded?

I don't know how to solve this problem. If you solve it, I appreciate you very much.
Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try comparison test with  $\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ for $x\neq 0$, at $x=0$ judge convergence by inspection.